# Integration boundaries in simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading the wikipedia article on the [integration factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). In the first section, "Use in solving first order linear ODE", they describe how to solve an ODE of the form

$$ y'  + P(x)y = Q(x) $$

> Finally, we can move the exponential to the right-hand side to find a general solution to our ODE:
>
> $$ y = e^{-\int_{s_0}^xP(s)d(s)} \int_{t_0}^x Q(t)e^{\int_{s_0}^t P(s)ds}dt  + C e^{-\int_{s_0}^xP(s)d(s)}$$

The article does not mention what $t_0$ and $s_0$ are. I would have thought that there is one initial condition, $x_0$, and both refer to that. But then, why use two different variables for the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s_0$ instead of $x_0$ is probably used to express that the lower boundary is arbitrary. Moreover, you can use any fixed anti-derivative instead of the definite integral, the additive constant cancels in the end.

It is also possible that this is a case of multiple authors using multiple conventions and multiple degrees of explicitness.

---

Using an initial value $y(x_0)=y_0$ one can specialize the integration and used parameters to
$$
e^{\int_{x_0}^x P(s)\,ds}·y(x)-e^{\int_{x_0}^{x_0}…}·y_0=\int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^t P(s)\,ds}·Q(t)\,dt
$$
and thus
$$
y(x)=y_0·e^{-\int_{x_0}^x P(s)\,ds}+\int_{x_0}^x e^{-\int_{t}^x P(s)\,ds}Q(t)\,dt
$$

Comment: Say I am given an initial value $y(x_0) = y_0$. Then I can use $y_0$ to solve for $C$, but also it will imply that both $s_0 = x_0$, and $t_0 = x_0$, right?

Comment: Yes, using $s_0=t_0=x_0$ would then be the most intuitive choice.

Comment: Two follow-ups: The general expression had $C e^{-\int \cdots}$, but you have $y_0 e^{\int \cdots}$, is that a typo? Second: in the second line, your inner inner integral is from $t$ to $x$ - shouldn't that be $x_0$ to $x$?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the form of the differential equation as $y'=Py+Q$. You are right, with the given form the signs must be opposite. -- No, this is combining both the exponentials before and after the integral sign, that is the difference of the integrals over $[x_0,x]$ and $[x_0,t]$..